# Access objects from FragmentActivity inside Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using objects from my main activity in some of my fragments, one of these is the SpeechHelper which is defined in my MainActivity and used in all fragments.

I know two methods to use this object in my fragments:

-The first one is to pass it to the Fragment in it's constructor.

-The second one is to do this:

```
 ((MainActivity) getActivity()).speechHelper.speak(getString(R.string.flashlight),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH);
```

I'm not sure how this method works, morover it crashes my app early on MainActivity lifecycle.

I'd like to know what ways exist to do this and what's the preferred method to access objects from my MainActivity (FragmentActivity) in my Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is the preferred method.  Equally accepted is to pass it in via a call post-constructor, if necessary.  The method you use above only works if speechHelper is public, or if its protected and the fragment is in the same package.  It's generally a bad idea to access variables directly like that, as it violates separation of concern and can cause a variety of secondary problems if you refactor.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of places i have worked with have the main activity implement a listener interface. You the bind to that in on attach of the fragments and have public methods in your activity that use that listener instance to run code inmain activity.